# Why does Integer pointer when increased by 1 differ from when increased by 2

Tags: pointers

Would love to understand what is causing the difference in values when increasing Integer pointer by 1 and 2.

So I have the following code

```
int i1 = 15;
int *iptr = &i1;
```

When printing the value for `*iptr` we obviously expect to get 15 but when now I have increased by 1 i.e

```
iptr = iptr + 1
```

When I print out the value I get 0 however when increased by 2 i.e `iptr = iptr + 2` I get **1795094656**

Why is this the case

Comment: Undefined behavior isn't predictable

Comment: I do not understand this comment

Comment: Your code is performing an invalid read of memory, which is undefined behavior.  The implementation is free to do anything it wishes, including printing seemingly random values.  Probably a dupe, but my quick search isn't finding one.

Comment: What do you expect to be printed? Are you trying to increment the value the pointer is referencing?

Comment: I have no expectations I am just trying to understand how pointer are actually operating, so I created a int value the assigned pointer to it print the address and value then increased the pointer by 1 then do the same print the address and value and I noticed address changes and value was 0 when increased by 1 however when increased by 2 the value because so very large i.e 1795094656 so I wonder why such a big number how did we get here make sense

Answer (score 1):

Because you are simply increasing the address value that the pointer **iptr** points to rather than the value that is stored in that address.
To increase or change the value, all you need to do is to use

```
*iptr = index + 1
```

And the reason you are getting these strange numbers is that you are accessing random addresses of which values are not known.

Comment: Interesting thanks for the answer really appreciate it really sound just about right just not sure if that's correct pointer gurus will help me out here so I can tick this question of on the answer you gave